# PdfSharp on Mono

Tags: .net, linux, macos, mono, pdfsharp

Has anyone tried to port [PdfSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/) library to Mono? I just ran [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) against PdfSharp.dll v1.2 beta and I am getting about 12 P/Invoke errors and 10 or so Mono TODOs. Just wondering if anyone has ported PdfSharp over to Linux and OSX, if so, how did it go? Trying to evaluate if PdfSharp is a good candidate for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gabriel Burt is using it for his [PDFMod](http://gburt.blogspot.com/2009/07/pdf-mod.html) utility, which mean it can certainly be used for manipulating PDF documents. However, he uses a different library (Poppler) for rendering, so I suspect that the P/Invokes and TODOs are in the rendering code, particularly Windows Forms.

In short, as long as you don't use codepaths that hit the P/Invokes and TODO, it should work fine.